# Connect SQL Server 2008 database with tally erp in c# .net

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Can some guide me is there any chance to migrate data from tally ERP9.0 to SQL Server 2008? If possible please let me know how. I am very new to SQL Server.

I want to make my software tally friendly so please suggest me any code for I can connect my database with tally to reduce tally software data entry work.

I want to convert my database in other format which is friendly with tally & reduce the data entry work. suggest me any idea which fulfill my need.

Answer (score 2):

Tally contains a ODBC options look great but you need to understand bit TDL language of Tally to get the required data or Apart from the above two options I would suggest you to choose with Tally XML Interface (Kind of SOAP web service) which will give you real time data.

Another i found good guide http://www.rtslink.com/dx-fusion/getting-data-from-tally-into-sql-server.html

or http://www.rtslink.com/VB.NET-to-tally-Csharp-to-tally-ASP.NET-to-tally.html

In this guide you can see Tally ODBC Interface and  Tally XML Interface http://mirror1.tallysolutions.com/Downloads/TDL%20Developer/Tally.ERP%209%20-%20Integration%20Capabilities.pdf

Hope help you :)